Do all SMPS ICs have an internal dead-time for the MOSFETs, specifically the LTC7878?
I am trying to improve myself in power electronics and currently trying to build a Buck-Boost converter. I chose LTC7878 for this purpose since it meets my requirements.
My issue is that while I am simulating the LTC7878 circuit on LTspice, I am seeing massive current spikes on the MOSFET drain-to-source currents each time the respective MOSFET switches, in the range of 7-10 ns, especially at the drain of the MOSFET at the top gate on the input. I looked up why this could be happening and came to conclusion that it is either related to having no dead-time for the switching or a simulation issue.
Though when I observe the waveforms, I believe that I see a dead-time during the switching operation as the top and bottom gate drivers are not switching at the same time.
The only instance the datasheet mentions dead-time is on page 21 and it is related to power losses. But I am not sure if dead-time is introduced by the IC itself or should be done externally.
I think I should fix those spikes if they are real as they can possibly create problems for the overall circuit and also affect the MOSFET selection.
The figure below is from the example circuit of LTC7878 on LTspice.
V_in: 8V DC
V_out: 12V DC
I_out: 2.4A
MOSFET: BSC123N08NS3
Input Capacitance C_iss: 1430 pF
Output Capacitance C_oss: 385 pF
Reverse Transfer Capacitance C_rss: 15 pF

Current spikes of the MOSFET connected to TG1 during buck operation.

The schematic of the circuit.
Thank you for your time.
EDIT: I added an RC filter to the input of the gates of the MOSFETs with a fairly small time constant. This attenuated the spikes but I don't think I should need to do this.
EDIT2: Added more information and a figure.

Welcome -- what is the schematic? What is the transistor capacitance (Coss), and what current would you expect to flow through it given the dV/dt?

Hello @TimWilliams, thank you for your response. I've added the schematic and the capacitance values. The switching frequency is fairly small in the graph and the circuit I provided (around 100 kHz). I plan to increase it up to 400 kHz. With that, I believe dt decreases even further and the spikes consequently get higher. The current that I expect to flow is in the range of 4-11 amps.

Switching frequency doesn't control the height of this peak -- you need to zoom in and look at the dV/dt (rate of change, slope of the rising edge) of the voltage waveform. It's not a µs feature, but ns.

Yes I realized what you meant after I commented. The spikes are in the range of 7-10 ns. This is a current waveform by the way.

Those currents come from the reverse recovery of the body diode of the low-side MOSFET, which is the one driven by BG1 (if the config wasn't a sync buck then the spikes would come from the reverse recovery of the freewheeling diode). You may want to plot the VDS (drain-to-source voltage) and VGS (drive voltage or gate-to-source voltage) as well to see the effect more clearly. NOTE: You shouldn't see the same spikes if you plot the inductor current.
Those spikes will also cause reverse recovery losses and reduce the overall efficiency (not much, but it's still there).

The dead time that is inserted between the low- and high-side driving signals is not under your control. The IC might have a fixed dead time, or it might be  able to adjust it dynamically (adaptive dead time control).
To mitigate the spikes, what you can do are:-

Slow down the switching by adding gate stopper resistors or RC networks as you already tried. The problem with this is, if you slow down more the duration that a MOSFET operates in linear (ohmic i.e. VGS-dependent resistor) region increases which ultimately reduces the efficiency further.

Add a snubber across the drain-source of the low-side MOSFET.

Use a different MOSFET with different reverse recovery characteristics.


You can ignore those spikes or mitigate them depending on your practical requirements. They bring EMI problems so if you have conducted and radiated emission problems in a practical circuit you may want to mitigate them. If you don't have any EMI problems, and if you don't see a significant reduction on efficiency due to the spikes, then you can ignore them as long as the characteristics are within the SOA limits.

I have used a Schottky across the bottom FET to deal with this in the past.

My favorite anecdote / learning experience was with the LTC3810, the eval board of which uses something like 10A transistors, and a singular B1100 diode to clamp recovery... which summarily accomplishes absolutely nothing (body diode Vf is less than the diode's), in fact it increases loss by increasing node capacitance slightly. That dev board also had terrible EMI (couple ns pulses from switching edges to all lines). Synchronous controllers with excessive dead time (meaning, more than ~zero) are a pet peeve of mine.

What kind of Schottky should I use? I could not observe any difference when I connected one across the FETs.

Thank you for the response @RohatKılıç. I will try to implement a snubber circuit. I tried to use the MOSFET given in the EVAL board as well but observed very similar spikes. The switching frequency is already at 100 kHz and I wish to increase it further to 400 kHz area. I should mitigate them as the power source is a part of an RF project I am working on. EMI is an issue. I don't know how to evaluate these spikes in the SOA... Are they pulses whose frequency is the switching frequency and with a duty cycle of <1%?..

@OpenBrainedProf. you may want to check the spike peaks and duration (reverse recovery time) as well as the Vds of the MOSFET and compare these against the SOA graphs (bottom left corner on p.4 of the MOSFET datasheet, although it contains info for pulses no smaller than 1 us). One other thing is the possibility of destruction due to the reverse recovery (unlikely, in your case). Finally, you may want to calculate the reverse recovery loss (1/2 QVf, details can be found online) along with temperature rise for extreme situations. In your case I don't see any extreme situation, though.

@RohatKılıç I see. I believe I'm in the safe zone. The duration of the spikes are in the range of 5-15 ns and with the Vds I'm measuring (I'm aware I have not included any information about this in the post) in LTspice, the location on the SOA graph is pretty safe. Though I am not sure if the spikes are gonna be a problem for the current limiter that I will be using, but I think that's a question for another post. I will make sure to check for the possibilities you mentioned. Thank you for your help! I wish you the very best day.
